# In Promise, response.status returns other Promise rather than the status code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have some Javascript code that makes a HTTP request to a server, like this:

```
export const getUserByID = id => {
  return Axios
          .get(`${BaseURL}/usuarios/${id}`)
          .then(response => response.status)
}
```

And I want it to return the status code from the HTTP request. The thing is when I do `console.log(getUserByID(id))`, the browser console prints a Promise rather than just the status code from the HTTP status, and I want to compare that status code to a number that means the status code I want to match:

```
if (getUserByID(id) === 204) {
 // do stuff
}
```

When I do `console.log(getUserByID(id) === 204)` I keep getting `false` I think because of the Promise I get returned rather than just a number. What should I do?

Comment: `getUserByID` DOES return a promise, so when you console.log the result of the function, you're logging a promise. you could do something like `getUserById(x).then(r => console.log(r))` if you want to log the result

Comment: using TypeScript and a lint will help u alot in these situations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getUserByID()` returns a Promise, so you need to wait for it to resolve in order to get the response status code. For example like this:

```
getUserByID(id).then((status) => {

    if (status === 204) {
        // do stuff
    }
}).catch(console.error);
```

or if you are in an `async` function you can use `await` keyword:

```
const status = await getUserByID(id); // it will work only inside an `async` function
if (status && status === 204) {
    // do stuff
}
```